# string === fails with equal strings

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Edit: Not a duplicate as this is not a question about using === vs ==. Both of those methods fail.

First two lines from csv:

`email,Product,Term,Rate
example@gmail.com,New,24 Months,1.99%`

I have tried both === and == in an if statement but it always fails. Here is the code I use. First I create the array from a csv file. Then I loop through that array. When I echo on the second to the last line the output is `example@gmail.com - example@gmail.com`.

This works with `if(line[0] === 'New'){` until I add in the email column in my csv sheet, but now even running `if(line[1] === 'New'){` does not work if the email column is there. I checked again, and by removing the email column, it works fine. Everything is formatted as text in the csv.

```
casper.then(function readFile() {
        var stream = fs.open('ck.csv', 'r');
        var line = stream.readLine();
        var lineArray = [];
        while(line) {
            lineArray.push(line);
            line = stream.readLine();
        }

    casper.eachThen(lineArray, function(response) {
        line = response.data.split(',');

        this.echo(line[0] + ' - ' + email);

        if(line[0] === email && line[1] === 'New'){
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96312/discussion-on-question-by-michael-st-clair-string-fails-with-equal-strings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure both `email` and `line[0]` trimmed. (Use `email = email.trim()`)

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `===` if common javascript standards are used - e.g. no `new String(...)` is used.

Answer (score -1):

You can also use the localeCompare() Method
If they are equal, you'll get 0. And we all know !0 is true.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_localecompare.asp

```
if(!line[0].localeCompare(email) && !line[1].localeCompare('New')){}
```